# Saving array in session c# error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to save array in session and trying to get it back.
The following is the code. But i get the following error when i invoke the WebMethod. I am using c#. VS2010

error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at xmlRW1.Service1.logic() in
>   C:\Users\uydarp\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\xmlRW1\xmlRW1\Service1.asmx.cs:line 86

```
[WebMethod]
    public int logic()
    {
        int[] myArray = { 1,2,3,4};
        Session["MyArray"] = myArray; 

        int[] myArray2 = (int[])Session["MyArray"];
        int firstElement = myArray2[0];

        return firstElement;
    }
```

Comment: What is session timeout value in web.config?

Comment: I don't find any timeout in the web.config file. All i have is <compilation debug="true" > and <authentication mode="Windows" /> in the web.config file.

Comment: Use [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SessionState is disabled by default in `asmx` services. You can enable it by changing the `WebMethod` attribute to explicitly enable it:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public int logic()
{
    int[] myArray = { 1,2,3,4};
    Session["MyArray"] = myArray; 

    int[] myArray2 = (int[])Session["MyArray"];
    int firstElement = myArray2[0];

    return firstElement;
}
```